# php search string in another string from array

Tags: php, arrays, find

I need something like this

```
$keywords = array('google', 'yahoo', 'facebook');

$mystring = 'alice was going to the yahoo CEO and couldn't him her';

$pos = strpos($mystring, $keywords);

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$keywords' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
}
```

Basically I need to search several terms in a string if find if any exists in the string.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to set the keywords /search to case insensitive

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Find if any of the keywords in an array exist in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596764/php-find-if-any-of-the-keywords-in-an-array-exist-in-a-string)

Comment: @DipeshParmar what about case insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the keywords and stop when you find at least one:

```
$found = false;

foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    if (stripos($mystring, $keyword) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$found) {
    echo sprintf("The keywords '%s' were not found in string '%s'\n",
        join(',', $keywords),
        $mystring
    );
}
```

Alternatively, use regular expressions with an alternation:

```
$re = '/' . join('|', array_map(function($item) {
    return preg_quote($item, '/');
}, $keywords)) . '/i';

if (!preg_match($re, $mystring)) {
        echo "Not found\n";
}
```

Comment: does it still work if I have amazon in the keywords but amazon.com in the content/string  ? or amazon in the keywords and Amazon in the string ?

Comment: @DoingThings Did you try that?

Comment: @Doing nope, it's case insensitive.